# Java generics has-a declaration

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic AVL tree class declared as:

```
public class AVLTree<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

I get compiler errors in another class whenever I try to initialize the avl tree class as generics in the constructor.

```
public class PQAVL<T> {
private AVLTree<T extends Comparable<T>> avl;
    public PQAVL() {
        avl = new AVLTree<T extends Comparable<T>>(true);
    }
}
```

I have tried several different declarations all receiving errors. Does anyone know how I would declare this correctly?

Comment: When I see a question saying that there was an error without specifying what the error was, I'll vote to close as "lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem" 9 times out of 9. Unless you're using an Apple II, error messages actually say something other than just "Error", and they do that for a reason: The information is useful in diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `<T extends ...>` is used when declaring a new type variable.

You cannot declare a new type variable when declaring a variable or field. Nor can you declare a new type variable as a tpe argument for an initialization expression such as

```
avl = new AVLTree<T extends Comparable<T>>(true);
```

You'll need to change your class to something like

```
public class PQAVL<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private AVLTree<T> avl;
    public PQAVL() {
        avl = new AVLTree<T>(true);
    }
}
```

so that the type parameter is declared at the class level and has the appropriate bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `public class PQAVL<T>` needs to be `public class PQAVL<T extends Comparable<T>>`.

What you currently do accepts any T as a generic to the class, then ensure at a lower level that it is Comparable. You have to do this at the class declaration level.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `AVLTree<T>`.

The "`extends Comparable<T>`" part just specifies a restriction on what `T` can be, but isn't something you specify when declaring variables of that type. You only specify that when you declare the type itself.

By the way, it's an odd choice of wording to say "has-a declaration"; typically we just call "avl" a "field" here.